# How do I measure couchbase read write latency?

Tags: java, couchbase

I want to measure the individual **latency** for *Read* and *Write* operation on Couchbase server.

Can someone please suggest me how do I measure it?
My Tech Stack is: Couchbase Server 4.5 and Java SDK 2.4.x.

Thanks in advance.